# Kinetic.JS Image Unable to Drag After Using Pixel Detection

Tags: javascript, html, kineticjs

I'm using `Kinetic.JS` library for developing HTML5 Apps.
I used Kinetic.Image to load an image (in `.PNG` format), and using pixel detection to detect only the non-transparent part of my image. The problem is I can't drag my image properly although I've set the `draggable` property to `true` and using `saveImageData` method. 
Image is dragged well before (using `path` detection). Any solution guys? 
This is my code:

```
   var beeObj = new Image();
        beeObj.onload = function(){ 
            bee = new Kinetic.Image({ //bee is global variable
            x: 325 - 45,
            y: 145 - 83,
            image: beeObj,          
            draggable: true         
        });
        lineLayer.add(bee); 
        lineLayer.draw();
        bee.saveImageData();
   };
   beeObj.src = directory + "smile_bee.png";
```

Comment: NB: Kinetic.JS version: kinetic-v3.10.4.js

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no DetectionType inside your image loader..
it should be something like

```
bee = new Kinetic.Image({ //bee is global variable
        x: 325 - 45,
        y: 145 - 83,
        image: beeObj,          
        draggable: true,
        DetectionType: 'Pixels'         
    });
```

and on mouse out you can use the same function i.e

bee.saveImageData();

and also end the whole onload function with the same function
then it will work

Now Eric has release v4+
so now there is no Pixel Detection type

you can use something like

```
    image.createImageBuffer();
```

// clear image buffer

```
     image.clearImageBuffer();
```

Hope this hels..

Regards